# ADF: Set icons in dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, jsf, oracle-adf

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

In my application, I have some popup with dialogs and its default Ok/Cancel buttons, with dialog and popup cancel listeners working fine.

Now, I have been requested to put icons in Ok/Cancel buttons.
It's easy with normal command buttons (there is an icon attribute), but I don't know how to do it in dialog default buttons

I'm trying to avoid remove default buttons and insert custom command buttons to accept and cancel.
Is there any easier/customizable way to do it?

Any idea would be very helpful. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ADF Skinning. Extract the style class (which are applied by default by the framework) from the buttons (using Firebug, Google, ...) and 'override' the style class to include your desired icon.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It seems to be the right solution, but I have more complex requirements, with more checks to do, and I can't process the style with jquery. But your suggestion is true: actually, all autogenerated buttons from a dialog have some shared classes and IDs.

Comment: But the checks you need to do, don't have anything to do with the style you are using (unless it is?). The behaviour of the default buttons them self can be checked using the actionListener.